# writing events for UIswitch in collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I am trying to write events for UI switch and UI segmentation control in UI collection view.

I declared the UIswitch and UIsegmentation control in collection view cell.

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *mySegmentedControl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *Myswitch;
```

and access it from view controller.m

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
 CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell.Myswitch.isOn)
{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"!Alert"
                                                message:@"Do you want to exit the application?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert show];
}
else
{

}
}
```

But UI switch and segmentation control both not works for me. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the future please don't repost your questions. Edit them as needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` in method in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cellIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.mySwitch.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.mySwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    //another cell setup code
    return cell;
}
```

2. Implement callback method:

```
- (void) switchValueChanged: (UISwitch *) sender {
    NSInteger index = sender.tag;
    //your code
}
```

3. Remove that code from `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Comment: is the above solution applicable to UI segmentation control also ?

Comment: Yes, it is applicable to any UIControl subclass actually

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` as it will dequeue a new empty `CollectionViewCell`. `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` should really only be called in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

If you want to access the cell for a given index path say

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath];
```